# how to handle empty linq Queries

Tags: c#, linq

I'm sure there is a better way of writing the following would love a few pointers on how to best go about it

essentially i cannot guarantee that a list of item contains a specific item i'm after and in trying to return a value based upon said item.

```
class item
{
string Brand;
string Product;
decimal Value;
}

//List is created and filled elsewhere
List<item> _items;

void DoStuff()
{
decimal desiredValue = 0;

   try
     {
    var XXX = _items
             .Where(x=>x.Brand == "brand1")
             .Where(x=>x.Product == "product1")
             .First();

    desiredValue = XXX.Value;
     }
    catch()
     { 
     //Empty Catch Bugs me
     }
//Do something with desiredValue
   }
}
```

Comment: BTW, as nobody has pointed it out you have used single `=`, whereas c# uses `==` for equality. Probably just a typo in your question but thought id point it out just in case ;)

Comment: yeah just a typo i'll fix thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use:

```
decimal? result = _items.Where(x => x.Brand == "brand1")
                        .Where(x => x.Product == "product1")
                        .Select(x => (decimal?) x.Value)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that here the `Select` clause is fetching something which is a *non-nullable* decimal, but explicitly converting it to `decimal?` so that you can then tell the difference between "there was a result, but it was 0" and "there weren't any results":

```
if (result == null)
{
    // No results
}
else
{
    decimal realResult = result.Value;
    // whatever...
}
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
Item result = _items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Brand == "brand1" && 
                                         x.Product == "product1");

if (result == null)
{
    // No results
}
else
{
    decimal value = result.Value;
    // Proceed...
}
```

Comment: I went so far as to wrap FirstOrDefault in an extension that allowed you to pass in the desired default if default<T> wasn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `First()`, use `FirstOrDefault()`, which will return null, which you can then check for.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result= _items.Where(x=>x.Brand = "brand1" && x.Product="product1").FirstOrDefault()

if (result!=null)
{
    // get the first
    var firstItem = result.value;
}
```